# how to reuse a variable with everything and its value in another page of my project

Tags: javascript

im working on a e-commerce and im trying to do the page where you fill your info, but i cant use my variable cart, or my total.textContent i just need to show my cart, the total of the cart and my form but i cant use any of my variables or functions

`enter code here`

```
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    
    const cartContainer = document.getElementById("cart-items");
    
    let cart = [];
    
    export let stock = [
    
        {id: 1, item: "Playera blanca - Logo rojo", precio: 265, imagen: '<img class="cart-review-img" src="./images/Playera blanca - Logo rojo.png" alt="">'
}];
    
    const upDateCart = () => {
        cartContainer.innerHTML = ""
    
        cart.forEach((prod) => {
            const div = document.createElement("div")
            div.className = ("cart-review-cotainer")
            div.innerHTML = `
            <div class="cart-image col-md-5">
                ${prod.imagen}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column  justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <p id="cart-item-name">${prod.item}</p>
                    <p id="cart-item-price">${prod.precio}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 delete-container">
                <button onclick="deleteItem(${prod.id})" id="delete-item"><img class="delete-img" src="./images/trash-solid.svg" alt=""></button>
            </div>
            `
            cartContainer.appendChild(div)
    
           localStorage.setItem("newCart", JSON.stringify(cart))
           
        })
        total.innerText = cart.reduce((acc, prod) => acc + prod.precio, 0)
    }
    
    if(localStorage.getItem("newCart")) {
        newCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCart"))
        console.log(newCart)
        upDateCart()
    }
    
    window.deleteItem = deleteItem;
    
    window.cart = cart;
    
    window.test = test;
    
    window.newCart = newCart;
```

[my files in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXKuE.png)

Comment: Yes, `localStorage.setItem("newCart", JSON.stringify(cart))` is the way to go. Just remember to `localStorage.getItem("newCart")` in the right place.

Comment: Could you give me a little more details? I've been stuck on this for a while without finding an answer, because its working with my localstorage is working with my index.html but i cant use it with my checkout.html

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't run your snippet, but I guess

```
   if(localStorage.getItem("newCart")) {
        newCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCart"))
        console.log(newCart)
        cart = newCart;        //  add this line maybe?
        upDateCart()
    }
```